# How to get rid of the "Ago" in a time format?

Tags: i18n-l10n

When translating to another language, a lot of things are in place, so much that most of translating goes with ease. However one thing seems very hard get done: getting rid of the "ago" in the format: "2 hours 23 minutes ago" while keeping the translation as it is.

Such format is available when adding a field like: "Authored on" and choosing the "Time Ago" format. 
in many languages, like French and German: ago's equivalent is supposed to be in the beginning of the time format: like "Depuit 2 heurs", meaning "2 hours ago".

Some of the terms like "hour" and "day" are already readily translated in many languages (if the language is added along with translation module), and some can be done in similar way: by visiting `admin/config/regional/translate` and searching in **String contains:** search area: For instance if Seconds are not translated , and hours are , seconds can be translated in a way similar to hours when searching for hours.

By searching for "ago" you can see `%time ago` but no changes are visible in the final page, removing `ago` or replacing it won't work, and nothing will change.

I came up with two solutions:

1-By changing the **past format** in the settings of *authored on* from `@interval ago` to `[depuis] @interval [ago]`. In this case @interval is accordingly translated depending on the language choosen here, but `[depuis]` and `[ago]` will show up in all languages.

2-
By changing the *authored on* settings of **past format** from `@interval ago` to just `@interval` and  changing the title in the English site from `Authored on` to `Authored .. ago` and in the translated version to something like `Publié depuis..` (In that last one, just by placing this title as a translation of the title in the English site, like doing view's settings translations..)

Is there any more obvious approach?

Comment: Can you explain more about how you're trying to translate the `%time ago` and how it's not working? Are you actually trying to translate it, or use a completely new time format in all langs (including English) that doesn't have that expression? If yes, then it makes the most sense to create a new Date format, and translate it, and not change the existing "ago"-one.

Comment: filtering in `/admin/config/regional/translate` for the term `ago` gets me `%time ago` and `@interval ago` changing either of this to `depuis %time` or just `%time`, but neither changes anything. Similar attempts wont work either in the "Authored on" settings. I am trying just what you have said without creating a new Date formate. How you create one of the form: `time lapsed: xx days and xx hours` or just `xx days xx hours`?

Comment: What do you mean by "neither changes anything"? How are you testing it? Did you change the English string or the translations? Did you rebuild cache and visited a page with that string in another language? I would create a date field with the label "Time lapsed" and create a new Date format to apply to that field.

Comment: I am working in View. By editing *Authored on* , I change the title from the default (which is "Authored on") to "Submitted", in same time I remove "ago" word from `@interval ago`. When translating the page, I translate the title (originally "Authored on") to anything that goes with the format `xx days xx hours`. Therein translating the title, whatever that is, to the sentence `publie depuis` (which means: "Authored since").  The translation does automatically translate `xx days xx hours` to `xx jours xx heurs`. Thus most the problem is almost solved. But with no further control by language.

Comment: Continuing my last sentence: though not that necessary anymore in my situation, my original intension was to temper with the `@interval`, but there is no way to change it in another way, like ` xx days **and** xx hours **ago** ` in english (this is the original english version, just added "and" in the middle..) and make it ` **depuis** xx days **et** xx heurs ` in the Frence version.